# Using sequences to test topological properties for topological manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

“As a consequence of being second countable,1) topological manifolds can have at most countably many connected components.2) Moreover, every point possesses a countable neighbourhood basis, so that one can use sequences to test topological properties like continuity of mappings or closedness of subsets.”

I think 1) follows from the fact that in a topological manifold every component is open since every topological manifold is locally path connected. Am I correct or do the authors probably have a more simple argument? But I could not understand what the authors mean by 2). In particular, what does **countable** in countable neighborhood basis have to do with testing topological properties? Only Hausdorff condition must suffice

Comment: It is not clear to me what you think Hausdorffness has to do with testing topological properties.

Comment: I mean Hausdorffness lets one define convergence in topological spaces, nothing more, and that countability seems superfluous in testing topological properties as in metric spaces

Comment: No...Hausdorffness has absolutely nothing to do with defining convergence...

Comment: I mean convergence to a unique point as in metric spaces

Comment: OK, but uniqueness of limits has nothing to do with any of the "testing topological properties" that they are talking about.

Comment: I have not read much about sequences in topological spaces that is why my gueses were based only on metric space case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "testing topological properties" they mean statements like the following:

- If $A\subseteq X$, then $A$ is closed iff for any sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ and any $x\in X$, if $x_n\to x$ then  $x\in A$.
- If $f:X\to Y$, then $f$ is continuous iff for any sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ and any $x\in X$, if $x_n\to x$ then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

These statements are not true for arbitrary topological spaces (the "only if" parts are true but the "if" parts may not be), but they are true for second-countable spaces.  So in this way, the second-countability of manifolds allows you to use sequences to test topological properties in manifolds.

(Actually, though, this assertion is rather misleading, because these properties only require spaces to be *first-countable*, not second-countable.  First-countability is a local property, so any space which is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is first-countable.  So, even if manifolds were not required to be second-countable, you could still use sequences in these ways!)

Comment: Thanks, it was what I needed to know to understand what the authors meant

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology is has path connected components that are clopen. These connected components are each of its singleton subsets. There are uncountably many of them.

It is the second countability what gives you that there are at most countably many connected components. Since it is second countable there must be a countable basis of the topology. At you said the connected components are open, and therefore each one contains an element of the countable basis. Those elements are different for different components, since the components are disjoint. Therefore, the number of components must be at most countable.

Comment: Thanks, but I had assumed the second countability in my argument, what I implied was that the authors did not mention the fact that each component is open due to local path connectivity

Comment: @Selflearner You can deduce from local path connectivity, but local path connectivity follows from a much stronger condition in the definition that implies open connected components, and that is local isomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is connected.

Comment: But how would you deduce that each component is open only using the local homeomorphism? Taking a point in a component and proving that it is contained in an open set inside the component cannot be directly deduced in your way I think

Comment: Take a point $x\in M$. Since $M$ is manifold, there is a neighborhood $M\supset U\ni x$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected, so is $U$. Therefore, all points of $U$ belong to the same connected component as $x$. This implies that for every point in a connected component, there is a neighborhood of it in which all the points belong to that connected component. Hence, the connected component is open.

Comment: Thank you, it was **the** natural explanation for openness of components of manifolds